# Laravel form with post method is not submitting

Tags: html, laravel, forms, submit

I have a form posting a title and a body. When i submit, nothing happens. I have a `csrf` field and i'm using the post method.

I have tried numerous different ways to declare the action and the method. I have tried to call the `csrf` field in different ways also. None of that worked.

Route:

```
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostsController');
```

Create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    // removed @method('POST')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea name="body" placeholder="Body" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

PostsController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return "Form posted";
    }
```

Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    // 
}
```

Here i have all the available routes:
[image: php artisan route:list]

The store function in the PostsController is empty. So I expect to recieve an empty page when I submit, but nothing happens.

Comment: why do you need this: `@method('POST')`. Try running `php artisan route:list` and make sure you have a named route called `posts.store`.

Comment: add your controller code and model  as well.

Comment: please add your controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dilip hirapara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9978078/dilip-hirapara) gave the solution in a comment.

I removed:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

and added:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for creating a new database registry, or for editing an existing one?

If it's for creating, remove the `@method('POST')` bit altogether. If it's for editing, change it to `@method('PATCH')`.

Comment: creating a new one

Comment: why the downvote??
I supposed you got the model and controller right, but it seems not.
Anyway, there was nothing wrong with what I posted so this downvote is completely not deserved.

Comment: Also, remove the type="button" of the submit button in the view.

Comment: Thanks man! Maybe someone downvoted me because I didnt format properly the code, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  **@method('POST')**

```
<form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Body</label>
        <textarea name="body" placeholder="Body" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit  </button>
</form>
```

In your **controller**.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($request->all());
}
```

Comment: already removed it. And I tried every possible way of writing the csrf field. Nothing changes.

Comment: Can you remove `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">` and add `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit  </button>` not sure but try it.

Comment: that's it. Thanks friend!

Comment: Select the answer and upvot please

Answer (score 0):

```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Put this in your header file. Sometime for csrf we need to put this as a meta tag.